Powershell - Need to recursively loop through log files and aggregate count of occurrence of different strings by file
I have a directory with multiple log files. I was able to get the number of 4 digit errorID instances by file using the below command.

Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | select-string -pattern 'ErrorID:\d{4}' | group path | ft Name,Count

But I want to extend this further. I want to get count of each 4 digit errorID by file.
Example:
log1.txt 
There is an error! ErrorID:3211 - Please correct
There is an error! ErrorID:4443 - Please correct
There is an error! ErrorID:32 - Please correct
There is an error! ErrorID:3211 - Please correct
log2.txt
There is an error! ErrorID:547- Please correct
There is an error! ErrorID:5588 - Please correct
There is an error! ErrorID:4443 - Please correct
There is an error! ErrorID:4443- Please correct
Expecting output:
log1.txt
ErrorID:3211 2
ErrorID:4443 1
log2.txt
ErrorID:5588 1
ErrorID:4443 2


You can use nested Group-Object calls:
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | 
  Select-String -Pattern 'ErrorID:\d{4}\b' | 
  Group-Object Path -PipelineVariable groupPerFile |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Group | Group-Object { $_.Matches.Value } } |
  Format-Table Name, Count -GroupBy @{ Name='Log file'; Expression = { $groupPerFile.Name } }

Output with your sample data:

   Log file: C:\path\to\log1.txt

Name         Count
----         -----
ErrorID:3211     2
ErrorID:4443     1

   Log file: C:\path\to\log2.txt

Name         Count
----         -----
ErrorID:4443     2
ErrorID:5588     1


Fantastic! Worked like a charm on the first run! Thank you!

Glad to hear it, @Sam; my pleasure.

Try :
cd C:\Temp\test
$table = [System.Collections.Generic.List[pscustomobject]]::new()
$files = Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | select-string -pattern 'ErrorID:\d{4}' | group path #| ft Name,Count
foreach($file in $files)
{
   foreach($group in $file.Group)
   {
      $group.Line -match 'ErrorID:\d{4}' | out-null
      $errorNum = ($Matches.0).Substring(($Matches.0).Length - 4)

      $newRow = [pscustomobject]@{
         Name = $file.Name
         Error = $errorNum
      }
      $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
   }
}
$table  | group Error,Name

